# Error handling in ReactJs using Axios is behaving differently on android chrome vs macOs chrome

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am submitting a form generated using HTML5(in `ReactJs`) and the data of which I am sending to a REST service using `POST` request.

```
submitForm = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "http://localhost:8080/signup",
      data: this.formData //formData is an object which contains form data
    }).catch(error => {
      this.setState({
        isError: true,
        errorMessage: error.response.data.errors[0].message
      });
    });
  };
```

Here, `errorMessage` is the state object which will be printed to the UI as an alert box.
Now, on my system, when I am submitting the form I am getting the alert box perfectly, but when I submitting the same data from chrome on my android device, I am getting this below error:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TYpeError): Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
```

I am quite surprised why `data` is a valid object on macOS browser then.
Any suggestions please.

Comment: do you get proper message on alert dialogue ?

Comment: on laptop, yes.

Comment: how are sending post request from android chrome ? targeting your IP address ?

Comment: Yes, using http://192.168.0.7:3006/signup

Comment: why not  192.168.0.7:8080/signup ?

Comment: because that's what `yarn` gave me. My app is on port 3006

Comment: I would recommend you to connect your device with laptop and enable USB debugging. Then go to chrome://inspect to see running chrome instance on your phone and see your network calls response from dev tools